# MAMP 500 Internal Server Error. MAC OSX php 

Tags: php, mamp, xcache

No results from my php code on the MAMP just got a 500 internal server error. 
Also I don't know if has something to do with XCache installed, no idea what's it but comes with MAMP.
Here is my code. Trying to display an image binary stored on my mysql dB.

```
  <?php 
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("catlogo") or die(mysql_error());
  $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catlogo WHERE id=2");
  $image = mysql_fech_assoc($image);
  $image = $image['imagen'];

  header("Content-type:image/png");
  echo $image;

  ?>
```

Comment: can you edit and include the last lines of error_log?

Comment: Usually 500's aren't caused by PHP. Check if you have any rogue htaccess files.

Comment: Paulo H.  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Meca/geto.php on line 5

Comment: I just checked the php_error.log great helpful better than firebug!!

Comment: [04-Dec-2011 01:36:04] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/geto.php:15) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projectos/geto.php on line 14

Comment: A Notice message it's not an error. It only notices some things that should be fixed if we want to be a strict developer.

The PHP Warning you get it's telling you sent some text before a header command. Check geto.php on line 15 and previous code. Usually a single space or line before the <?php could break your headers.

Comment: Give us error log messages from Apache and PHP please - in MAMP under menu Log / Apache and Log / PHP.

Comment: @MethodistMX, logs are for investigating that kind of errors. Start there...

Answer (score 2):

php Syntax Error

line 5:

```
$image = mysql_fech_assoc($image);
```

replace:

```
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code would raise a fatal PHP error on the typo, "mysql_fech_assoc".

Comment: yes is mysql_fetch_assoc, 3 years and body noticed, also the edit improvement dind't let me the chance to add just one letter